# Google maps api error when 2 plugins loading at the same time

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question, might be jquery, might be google maps, might be wordpress :)

I'm building a plugin for ACF, i needed a google maps which i could draw on. All works, but i get the following error:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page.
>   This may cause unexpected errors.

Well that's correct because i also load the google maps acf plugin. But that's where it gets weird. I load my plugin with the following code:

```
    // validate google
    if( typeof window['google'] === 'undefined' )
    {
        $.getScript('https://www.google.com/jsapi', function(){
            google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: 'libraries=places,drawing', callback: function() {
                acf.fields.google_map_draw.set({ $el : $el }).init();
            }});
        });
   }
   else
   {
        google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: 'libraries=places,drawing', callback: function(){
            acf.fields.google_map_draw.set({ $el : $el }).init();
        }});
    }
```

We check if google maps is defined. This is also the way ACF loads its google maps api code.

So the question is, is it possible that both the plugins load on the same time and then when they finish one of them is later and gives the error.

And the other question, how can i fix this? Do i have to give a timeout so i can let the other plugin load?

Thanks in advance!

Wouter